# How to do "col(a)==null? col(b) : col(c)" column operation in Spark SQL's DataFrame using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava to do some data cleaning before machine learning and my dataframe look like below:

```
+-------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| userid|artistid|playcount|   badid| goodid|
+-------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
|2158448|10006467|        1|10006467|1244705|
|2144107|10009022|        5|10009022|1024524|
|1006831|10009473|        1|10009473|1010373|
|2011584|10016312|       13|10016312|1000127|
|2052189|10021776|        2|10021776|1082784|
|2052189|10022667|        1|10022667|1082784|
|1060325|10039984|        1|10039984|1001463|
|2077268|10043655|        1|10043655|1000597|
|1038421|10048281|        2|10048281|1256384|
|2116983|10055238|        1|10055238|1003509|
|2211143|10055238|       27|10055238|1003509|
|1000083| 1006162|        2| 1006162|1048788|
|1001371| 1006162|        1| 1006162|1048788|
|1001411| 1006162|        1| 1006162|1048788|
|1002138| 1006162|        3| 1006162|1048788|
|1009943| 1006162|        2| 1006162|1048788|
|1021747| 1006162|        4| 1006162|1048788|
|1031726| 1006162|        1| 1006162|1048788|
|1032062| 1006162|        2| 1006162|1048788|
|1036948| 1006162|        1| 1006162|1048788|
+-------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I need to generate a new DataFrame which contain current all columns and also add a new column in **Java**. The logic of this new "Column" is like this:

```
IsNull(Col('badid')) ? Col('artistid') : Col('goodid')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#when%28org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.Object%29) / [`otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#otherwise%28java.lang.Object%29):

```java
when(col("badid").isNull(), col("artistid")).otherwise(col("goodid"))
```

which is equivalent to SQL `CASE WHEN ... ELSE`:

```sql
CASE  
    WHEN badid IS NULL THEN artistid
    ELSE goodid
END
```

Comment: This is a brief and concise answer. Now, I know I need to "import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;" in my Java code and utitlize these API methods. Thanks a lot [zero323](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323)!!